# Move emails from subfolder to hard drive

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I am curious to know how to move emails from a specific subfolder to my hard drive. Basically, my inbox has about 20 subfolders. I want to be able to move all the emails from subfolder1 to my hard drive.

Is there a macro to specifically go to that folder and move all the emails onto my hard drive? Granted I do want to keep all the emails in .msg rather than being a .txt file.

Answer (score 1):

I bielive you can develop a VBA macro or add-in to get the job done. See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get started.

The [SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868727(v=office.15).aspx) method of the MailItem class saves the Microsoft Outlook item to the specified path and in the format of the specified file type. If the file type is not specified, the MSG format (.msg) is used. The file type to save can be one of the following *OlSaveAsType* constants: olHTML, olMSG, olRTF, olTemplate, olDoc, olTXT, olVCal, olVCard, olICal, or olMSGUnicode. For example:

```
 Sub SaveAsMSG() 
  Dim myItem As Outlook.Inspector 
  Dim objItem As Object 

  Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector 
  If Not TypeName(myItem) = "Nothing" Then 
   Set objItem = myItem.CurrentItem 
   strname = objItem.Subject 
   'Prompt the user for confirmation 
   Dim strPrompt As String 
   strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to save the item? " & _ 
   "If a file with the same name already exists, " & _ 
   "it will be overwritten with this copy of the file." 
   If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then 
    objItem.SaveAs Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\My Documents\" & strname & ".msg", olMSG 
   End If 
  Else 
   MsgBox "There is no current active inspector." 
  End If 
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should allow you to select outlook folder and hard drive folder, All emails in that folder and all sub folders will be saved to your HD

```
Option Explicit
Sub SaveMsgToFolders()
    Dim i, j, n As Long
    Dim sSubject As String
    Dim sName As String
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim sReceived As String
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim sFolderPath As String
    Dim SaveFolder As String
    Dim Prompt As String
    Dim Title As String
    Dim iNameSpace As NameSpace
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim olmItem As MailItem
    Dim FSO, ChosenFolder As Object
    Dim Folders As New Collection
    Dim EntryID As New Collection
    Dim StoreID As New Collection

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set iNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set ChosenFolder = iNameSpace.PickFolder ' // Chose Outlook Folder
    If ChosenFolder Is Nothing Then
GoTo ExitSub:
    End If

    Prompt = "Please enter the path to save all the emails to."
    Title = "Folder Specification"
    sPath = BrowseForFolder
    If sPath = "" Then
GoTo ExitSub:
    End If
    If Not Right(sPath, 1) = "\" Then
        sPath = sPath & "\"
    End If

    Call GetFolder(Folders, EntryID, StoreID, ChosenFolder)

    For i = 1 To Folders.Count
        sFolder = StripIllegalChar(Folders(i))
        n = InStr(3, sFolder, "\") + 1
        sFolder = Mid(sFolder, n, 256)
        sFolderPath = sPath & sFolder & "\"
        SaveFolder = Left(sFolderPath, Len(sFolderPath) - 1) & "\"
        If Not FSO.FolderExists(sFolderPath) Then
            FSO.CreateFolder (sFolderPath)
        End If

        Set SubFolder = olApp.Session.GetFolderFromID(EntryID(i), StoreID(i))
        On Error Resume Next
        For j = 1 To SubFolder.Items.Count
            Set olmItem = SubFolder.Items(j)
            sReceived = ArrangedDate(olmItem.ReceivedTime)
            sSubject = olmItem.Subject
            sName = StripIllegalChar(sSubject)
            sFile = SaveFolder & sReceived & "_" & sName & ".msg"
            sFile = Left(sFile, 256)
            olmItem.SaveAs sFile, 3
        Next j
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i
ExitSub:
End Sub

Function StripIllegalChar(StrInput)
    Dim RegX As Object

    Set RegX = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    RegX.Pattern = "[\" & Chr(34) & "\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\=\+\|\[\]\{\}\`\'\;\:\<\>\?\/\,]"
    RegX.IgnoreCase = True
    RegX.Global = True

    StripIllegalChar = RegX.Replace(StrInput, "")

ExitFunction:
    Set RegX = Nothing
End Function


Function ArrangedDate(sDateInput)
    Dim sFullDate As String
    Dim sFullTime As String
    Dim sAMPM As String
    Dim sTime As String
    Dim sYear As String
    Dim sMonthDay As String
    Dim sMonth As String
    Dim sDay As String
    Dim sDate As String
    Dim sDateTime As String
    Dim RegX As Object

    Set RegX = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    If Not Left(sDateInput, 2) = "10" And _
    Not Left(sDateInput, 2) = "11" And _
    Not Left(sDateInput, 2) = "12" Then
        sDateInput = "0" & sDateInput
    End If

    sFullDate = Left(sDateInput, 10)

    If Right(sFullDate, 1) = " " Then
        sFullDate = Left(sDateInput, 9)
    End If

    sFullTime = Replace(sDateInput, sFullDate & " ", "")

    If Len(sFullTime) = 10 Then
        sFullTime = "0" & sFullTime
    End If

    sAMPM = Right(sFullTime, 2)
    sTime = sAMPM & "-" & Left(sFullTime, 8)
    sYear = Right(sFullDate, 4)
    sMonthDay = Replace(sFullDate, "/" & sYear, "")
    sMonth = Left(sMonthDay, 2)
    sDay = Right(sMonthDay, Len(sMonthDay) - 3)
    If Len(sDay) = 1 Then
        sDay = "0" & sDay
    End If
    sDate = sYear & "-" & sMonth & "-" & sDay
    sDateTime = sDate & "_" & sTime
    RegX.Pattern = "[\:\/\ ]"
    RegX.IgnoreCase = True
    RegX.Global = True

    ArrangedDate = RegX.Replace(sDateTime, "-")

ExitFunction:
    Set RegX = Nothing
End Function

Sub GetFolder(Folders As Collection, EntryID As Collection, StoreID As Collection, Fld As MAPIFolder)
    Dim SubFolder       As MAPIFolder
    Folders.Add Fld.FolderPath
    EntryID.Add Fld.EntryID
    StoreID.Add Fld.StoreID
    For Each SubFolder In Fld.Folders
        GetFolder Folders, EntryID, StoreID, SubFolder
    Next SubFolder
ExitSub:
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
End Sub


Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As String) As String
    Dim ShellApp As Object
    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
    BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, OpenAt)

    On Error Resume Next
    BrowseForFolder = ShellApp.self.Path
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case Mid(BrowseForFolder, 2, 1)
    Case Is = ":"
        If Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = ":" Then
            BrowseForFolder = ""
        End If
    Case Is = "\"
        If Not Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = "\" Then
            BrowseForFolder = ""
        End If
    Case Else
        BrowseForFolder = ""
    End Select

ExitFunction:
    Set ShellApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: With this macro, how would I go about and setting up the rule for the emails that are already existing. The emails that I currently have in this specific sub folder, how would I create the rule so that it  says to just look at the folder now, rather than setting a rule for when an email arrives?

Comment: @novicevba you don't need rule just run the macro as it is.